Does a for loop check if you are at the end of the iterable each iteration?
I am new to coding so for practice I was making a function that removes all of a certain character from any string passed into the function. I found that my for loop was not working as expected. It was not removing every '.'.
lst = ['.','.']

for item in lst:
    if item == '.':
        lst.remove('.')

print(lst)

Which outputs: ['.']
After trying different inputs and thinking about this, I came to the conclusion that a for loop will check if it is at the end of the list every iteration of the loop. Otherwise this loop would give an index error. As on the first iteration of the loop, the index of the loop is 0. It then removes the first '.', which leaves the list ['.']. Now on the second iteration index is 1, but list only has one element. So loop is out of index.
Is this true, or am I missing something?

In this case this is right. Therefore it is recommended to not modify a list while iterating over it but to iterate over a copy of to build a new list while iterating.

Yep, that's it. On the second iteration, the iterator recognizes it has gone past the end of the list and raises a StopIteration error. Its not the for loop itself, which just keeps calling the __next__ method on the iterator.

Ok. Thank you for the clarification and the way to fix this issue.

You are correct, except it's not the for that does the checking. for works generically for all iterables. It gets an iterator and repeatedly calls the iterator's __next__ method until that method raises a StopIteration exception. The list iterator keeps an index and raises the exception when the index is out of range.
We can see the same process without a loop:
>>> lst= ['.', '.']
>>> i_list = iter(lst)
>>> i_list.__next__()
'.'
>>> lst.remove('.')
>>> i_list.__next__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>>

